# How to set up 3 Columns with 1 Div Horizontally and Vertically Aligned in each column?

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to set up three columns and vertically and horizontally center the span in each of the columns. I've tried using flexbox and grid but it's not working out for me

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjL4L.jpg

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column ">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
</div>

.row{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.column{
    float:left;
    width:33.33%;   
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to horizontally center a <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of `grid` (for the outer layout) and `flexbox` for the columns content alignment:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    background: black;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 48px;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 48px;
}

.column {
    background: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
    <div class="column ">
        <span class="center">test</span>
    </div>
</div>
```